# Why didn't Thanos kill this character?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, thanos

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, when Thanos

> kills Loki and all the other Asgardians,

he then leaves

> Thor injured, instead of killing him.

Why?

Comment: Thanos likely assumed the vacuum of space would kill Thor, or simply leaving him to be destroyed by the explosion caused by the power stone.

Comment: yeah, maybe. Good precision.

Comment: I wondered the same thing. Maybe he felt it was a waste. Remember Thanos doesn't kill indiscriminately. He believes it's all to do with his destiny.

Comment: @Möoz exactly. Thanos is [lawful evil](http://easydamus.com/lawfulevil.html) in a D&D context. He kills as a means to accomplish his goals and vision of a new order, considering those goals to overrule the sanctity of life, but doesn't kill indiscriminately or for pleasure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I believe Thanos didn't kill for the sake of killing - he had a purpose.

With that in mind, he only killed Loki because he professed his "undying loyalty",  then immediately attempted to kill Thanos. Thanos would have seen this to be a lack of loyalty, hence he killed Loki - not because Loki was a threat, but because he lied.

Whereas Thor never did such a thing, hence he wasn't killed, despite being a potential threat.

If Loki never did what was mentioned above, he most likely would still be alive.

Comment: The quote was from memory, please feel free to correct to the exact quote.

Comment: Yes, I thought that *Infinity War* presented a fairly sympathetic portrayal of a character who was, in fact, a mass-murderer. Even though we can agree that his reasons did not objectively justify his acts, we can understand how he might, through various influences, believe that they do. He was not evil "just because" he wanted to be evil, he believed that the ends justified the means, not unlike other relatable, more deceived and desperate than pure evil villains like Darth Vader.

Comment: Also he tries to kill just half of the species

Answer (score 12):

Expanding on what Edlotihad said, Thanos would have thought that

> Thor would die in the explosion of the ship and also as Thor was beaten up Thanos would have thought that Thor wouldn’t be a threat to him because he does not posses any weapon and as thanos attacked nidavellir and killed almost all the dwarfs and stoped the forging process Thanos would also have thought that Thor wouldn’t be able to forge a new weapon as well.